# WPF Layout - Fill Height, Auto Scrollbar

Tags: wpf, layout, grid, ribbon

The `Grid` at the bottom contains a `ListBox`.  It stretches vertically, but the scrollbar does not appear when it reaches the bottom.

[image]

Layout --

```
<RibbonWindow ResizeMode="CanResize">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel>
            <Ribbon ... />

            <ListBox
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</RibbonWindow>
```

I have heard that `StackPanels` can cause this behavior, but replacing it with a `Grid` causes its own set of issues.

EDIT --

This Layout works -

```
<RibbonWindow ResizeMode="CanResize">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Ribbon Grid.Row="0" />

        <ListBox Grid.Row="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        />
    </Grid>
</RibbonWindow>
```

Comment: What problems are caused by using a `Grid`?

Comment: It wasnt directly caused by the Grid.  It was because I wasn't using the Grid.Row="x" tag for each child

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed the Grid.Row="x" tags, and then I could remove the StackPanel, and everything worked.